# JavaScript Prompt() input

Tags: javascript, alert

The code below runs `alert('Please enter your name!');` only when the user clicks **Cancel** on the prompt. I am trying to make the code also run said alert if the user doesn't input anything in the prompt box and clicks **Enter**. However, when they input nothing and click **Enter**, the code renders "Hello". How do I go about that?

```
var theName = prompt('What is your name?');

if(theName != null) {
   document.write('Hello, ' + theName);
}

else{
   alert('Please enter your name!');
}
```

Comment: [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt): _If the user clicks OK without entering any text, an empty string is returned._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Return value from `prompt`](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/met_win_prompt.asp):

> String. If the user clicks "OK", the input value is returned. If the user clicks "cancel", null is returned. If the user clicks OK without entering any text, an empty string is returned.;

Answer (score 1):

When the user clicks enter without entering any string the result will be "empty-string", so "".
You are just checking for null. Empty-string is not null. So the code works as expected.
You should check for null or "" instead.
A shortcut would be to abuse javascript a bit and just check for

```
if (theName) { ...} else { ... }
```

without checking against null at all, since null and empty-string are both false-ish in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

As @JohnnyMopp and Idos said, you'll get an empty string returned if the user clicks **Enter** without typing anything.  You can check for that by adding another condition to your `if` statement:

```
var theName = prompt('What is your name?');

if(theName != null && theName != "") {
   document.write('Hello, ' + theName);
}

else{
   alert('Please enter your name!');
}
```